# Object belonging to same page file?

Tags: winapi, memory-management, virtual-memory, win32-process

What is the way to figure out the that the set of objects belong to same page file or not?

I am using virtualAlloc() to allocate and commit the memory for my test application. I am creating 200 objects. I am also decommitting the memory at runtime so that it can be used by other processes. The 200 objects that are created can be freed randomly.

My problem is that how can I figure out that the two objects freed belong to same page file and hence if all the objects in the page file is deleted then I can decommit the memory.
Problem is that the release of the objects are not in contiguous manner.

Comment: It is unclear why you think you need to know the physical backing store used for paging out a certain object. If you are done with an object, dispose it and free its memory. If you need to handle objects as a group you need to track their lifetimes and free the memory when the last object is released.

Comment: Hi,
The reason is, I am not allocating the memory by requesting the memory from heap instead I am doing it by two step back. I will be only reserving the memory and then committing the memory as I need the objects. more Efficient way to manage memory.

Comment: That's how **all** of us are managing memory. Except, we let the pros do the complicated stuff and simply use their CRT implementation. You still have not provided an explanation of how the page file factors in.